# Select a specific option in <select>

Tags: angularjs

I want select the option following a specific rule, like below

```
<select class="right123" >
     <option ng-selected="'{{contact.Situation}}' == 'P' ? 'true' : 'false'">P</option>
     <option ng-selected="'{{contact.Situation}}' == 'B' ? 'true' : 'false'">B</option>
     <option ng-selected="'{{contact.Situation}}' == 'A' ? 'true' : 'false'">A</option>
     <option ng-selected="'{{contact.Situation}}' == 'N' ? 'true' : 'false'">N</option>
</select>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<select class="right123 ng-scope">
      <option ng-selected="'B' == 'P' ? 'true' : 'false'" value="P" selected="selected">P</option>
      <option ng-selected="'B' == 'B' ? 'true' : 'false'" value="B" selected="selected">B</option>
      <option ng-selected="'B' == 'A' ? 'true' : 'false'" value="A" selected="selected">A</option>
      <option ng-selected="'B' == 'N' ? true : false" value="N">N</option>
</select>
```

my current situation is B, but all the options in rendered HTML are with the propertie `selected=selected`

How can I selected a specific option following a rule ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use an expression without any interpolation like so:

```
 <option ng-selected=" contact.Situation === 'P' ">P</option>
 <option ng-selected=" contact.Situation === 'B' ">B</option>
 <option ng-selected=" contact.Situation === 'A' ">A</option>
 <option ng-selected=" contact.Situation === 'N' ">N</option>
```

Also note that `ngSelected` coerce all values into a Boolean so to your surprise:

```
// in javascript all strings are truthy except an empty string('')

'false' === true
```

From source code of `ngSelected`:

```
scope.$watch(attr[normalized], function ngBooleanAttrWatchAction(value) {
  attr.$set(attrName, !!value);
});
```

Comment: Didn't work as well. The rendered HTML shows `ng-selected="contact.Situation == 'P'"`and then I tryied again with the interpolation but doing some changes, like `ng-selected="{{contact.Situation}} == 'B'"` and in rendered HTML shows me `ng-selected='B == B'` but thats all.

Comment: Thank you, this clarify a lot for me. Works fine.